# Terminal Services for win XP

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

what's is the xp (64 bit) install, that adds "terminal services" in control panel along with other utilities.

I need to see who is logged on to a remote pc and/or release that connection etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en

Comment: possibly, but doesn't seem to be available for 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=160ce316-bf2b-48d0-a035-e2abbc55d8e8